# Webeil's Intro to Homological Algebra: does theorem 10.6.3 implicitly reindex cochain complexes to chain complexes?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $R$ be a ring, let $\mathbf{D^-(R-mod)}$ denote the derived category of bounded above *cochain* complexes of $R$-modules, and consider the total tensor product functor
$$
\otimes_R^\mathbf{L}: \mathbf{D^-(R-mod)} \times \mathbf{D^-(R-mod)} \to \mathbf{D^-(Ab Gps)}.
$$
I don't love this notation but I'm emulating Weibel for ease of translation. For reference, a nice pdf of chapter 10 of Weibel is available [here](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ehrm/palestine/weibel/10-derived_category.pdf).

For cochains $A,B \in \mathbf{D^-(R-mod)}$, theorem 10.6.3 reads
$$
\mathbf{Tor}_i^R(A, B) \cong H^{-i}(A \otimes_R^\mathbf{L} B).
$$
where $\mathbf{Tor}_i^R(A, B)$ is the hypertor functor.

Now, I am confused by the statement of the theorem because the hypertor functor is defined for *chain* complexes, while the total tensor product functor is defined on *cochain* complexes. My impression is that one makes sense of it by reindexing the cochain complexes $A,B$ to regard them as chain complexes when computing $\mathbf{Tor}_i^R(A, B)$. The proof of 10.6.3 indeed reindexes at one point, but the proof is sufficiently terse that I am struggling to understand how it plays into the statement of the theorem.

1. How should I regard $A,B$ as cochain complexes for the total tensor product, but as chain complexes for hypertor?
2. If the answer to 1 truly is "reindex", how can reindexing be canonical here?